# World Clock: Is there an easy way to access region settings?

Tags: android

As the post states I am working on a world clock page for my app.

Is there a way to access region codes to be able to make a world clock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need SimpleTimeZone (under Locales)

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html

Timezone IDs can be obtained from TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.
Hope it help. :)

Comment: Sweet, now to figure out how to convert that into an TextView to display the time for that time zone. :)