# Trying to find the best way to make a TextView display different timezone times

Tags: android, timezone

In continuation of my previous post:
[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168356/world-clock-is-there-an-easy-way-to-access-region-settings/19168491?noredirect=1#19168491)

I am looking for the best way to take a TextView and make it display the time for a different time zone than the one I am currently in.

I know the typical way is:

```
textView.setText(apiCode_or_text_or_variable_etc);
```

I am wondering what to put in the apiCode_or_text_or_variable_etc section.

Comment: I am not sure if I totally get the question, but do you already have the time value you want to display in the textview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt")); // or whatever timezone
String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());
```

now set it to the `TextView`:

```
textView.setText(gmtTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Time and TimeZone

Here are the docs on both.  It seems to do exactly what you want.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

So, in short, you could implement as follows

```
textView.setText(Time(TimeZone().getDefault().getID().toString());
```